# How to create C code using Mathlink

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I have studied examples of using mathlink from Visual Studio. The question is, I have a mathematica notebook file where the needed calculations are done. Now I want to make the same things but from my C program using Mathlink. Is there an automatic tool for converting the Mathematica notebook file to C code so that they will be called by using the mathlink?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question completely.  Do you need to call the Mathematica kernel from a C program, or [do you need to call some C functions from Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8140869/695132)?

Comment: I need to call mathematica kernel from a C program.

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for then?](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RunningMathematicaFromWithinAnExternalProgram.html)

Comment: not exactly. if you have a big mathematica notebook file, then it will be hard to convert all the input operators inside one by one to the C program. instead, I want to call the evaluate of all the notebook file and get the result from that evaluation.

Comment: I think you should clarify the question a bit.  The lack of answers shows people don't really understand it (neither do I).  If you are asking about converting Mathematica code to C code, well, `Compile[ ... , CompilationTarget -> "C"]` does do that in a way, but reusing the output source code is not going to be trivial at all (because it is intended to be loaded by the Mma kernel after compiled).  Generally: no, it's not possible to convert a *notebook* to C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a mathematica notebook file where the needed calculations are done. Now I want to make the same things but from my C program using Mathlink.

You should probably read the answers to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140869/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica

> Is there an automatic tool for converting the Mathematica notebook file to C code so that they will be called by using the mathlink?

The closest to an automatic conversion that I am aware of is using [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) with [`CompilationTarget -> "C"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompilationTarget.html?q=CompilationTarget&lang=en) in *Mathematica* version 8.

This is probably not what you want however, because it will require rewriting your code in a way that it can be handled by `Compile`.  Further, it is automatically linking the function rather than embedding it in an external program.